# Built-in function to get value of object if callable?

Tags: python, callable

```
class Thing():
    xyz = "I'm a string"

class Truc():
    def xyz(self):
        return "I'm a function"

def valueOrCalledValue(input):
    if callable(input):
        return input()
    else:
        return input

thing = Thing()
print valueOrCalledValue(thing.xyx)

>>> "I'm a string"

truc = Truc()
print valueOrCalledValue(truc.xyz)

>>> "I'm a function"
```

Is there a built-in function that does what my `valueOrCalledValue` does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [properties](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) using decorators to make it tidy.

Comment: This is probably the best solution to the problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any built-in function to do that. Alternatively, you could do this in one line using a "if else" expression:

```
print my_thing() if callable(my_thing) else my_thing
```

assigning it to a variable works the same way:

```
my_var = my_thing() if callable(my_thing) else my_thing
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this.  It's simpler and **always** works for all possible variants on "callable".

```
def valueOrCalledValue(input):
    try:
        return input()
    except TypeError:
        return input
```

Comment: Interested about what you mean by 'all possible variants on "callable"'. Can you explain or give examples?

Comment: Classes are callable (they instantiate objects). Functions are callable, and methods are callable. This method will only succeed on callable objects that require no arguments (but may accept kwargs).

Comment: This is actually much more pythonic: try it, and if it succeeds, then it was a duck. Otherwise, punch it a bit more and see if it quacks then.